# How to configure este to work with react-toolbox?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, postcss, react-toolbox

As recomended in este wiki, I would like to use react-toolbox to create components in material design. I have installed react-toolbox with npm. I got this error while trying to use button.

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/theme.css
Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: /home/alenka/Documents/bakalárka/esteDir/este/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/button
    at Error (native)
    at /home/alenka/Documents/bakalárka/esteDir/este/node_modules/postcss-load-config/index.js:51:26
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/theme.css 4:14-100 13:2-17:4 14:20-106
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/index.js
 @ ./src/browser/home/HomePage.js
 @ ./src/browser/app/routeConfig.js
 @ ./src/browser/app/Root.js
 @ ./src/browser/main.js
 @ ./src/browser/index.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://192.168.1.41:8080/__webpack_hmr ./src/browser/index.js
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/theme.css
Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: /home/alenka/Documents/bakalárka/esteDir/este/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/ripple
    at Error (native)
    at /home/alenka/Documents/bakalárka/esteDir/este/node_modules/postcss-load-config/index.js:51:26
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/theme.css 4:14-100 13:2-17:4 14:20-106
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/index.js
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/index.js
 @ ./src/browser/home/HomePage.js
 @ ./src/browser/app/routeConfig.js
 @ ./src/browser/app/Root.js
 @ ./src/browser/main.js
 @ ./src/browser/index.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://192.168.1.41:8080/__webpack_hmr ./src/browser/index.js
```

Could anybody help me please?